# Is it possible to reset parts of files already committed?

Tags: git

Thinking there are some files:

- A/1.cpp
- A/2.cpp
- A/3.cpp
- ...
- A/100.cpp
- B/1.cpp
- B/2.cpp
- C/1.cpp
- C/2.cpp
- C/3.cpp

After executing `git commit -a`, I want to revert the change to B/1.cpp and B/2.cpp.

Is there any easy way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to modify the existing commit. If you want to create a new commit instead, you already have the right command to restore them to their previous version; simply commit again after running that.

#### Method 1

First undo the commit:

```
git reset HEAD^
```

The changed files remain staged, so unstage the files you wanted to revert (yes, confusingly, this also uses `git reset`):

```
git reset B/1.cpp B/2.cpp
```

Then commit again:

```
git commit
```

#### Method 2

Reset the files to their previous version:

```
git checkout HEAD^ -- B/1.cpp B/2.cpp
```

They remain staged, so you can now amend your commit:

```
git commit --amend
```

Comment: Oh, I get it!
In method 2, `git checkout HEAD~1 -- B` is what I really wanted.

Comment: @Thomas, Instead of git reset, git restore will also unstage files from staged section.. correct me, If am wrong